# titanium android publish error

Tags: android, titanium

just trying to publish my titanium project for the google play store and facing this compilation error. what can I do from titanium keeping the same java version.

anybody have had the same issue and want to help me?

```
[INFO] :   Running dexer: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-Xmx1024M" "-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit" "-Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools" "-jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/21.1.2/lib/dx.jar" "--dex" "--output=/Users/dariorusignuolo/Desktop/titanium/entusiasmo/buongiornoentusiasmo/build/android/bin/classes.dex" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Desktop/titanium/entusiasmo/buongiornoentusiasmo/build/android/bin/classes" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/lib/titanium-verify.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/3.3.7/cloudpush.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/3.3.7/lib/aps-cloudpush-1.0.3.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/3.3.7/lib/google-play-services.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/com.revmob.ti.android/1.2.1/revmob.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/com.revmob.ti.android/1.2.1/lib/google-play-services-17.0.0.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/com.revmob.ti.android/1.2.1/lib/revmob-6.9.7.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/facebook/3.0.3/facebook.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/kroll-v8.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-analytics.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/aps-analytics.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-android.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/jaxen-1.1.1.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/kroll-common.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/titanium.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-app.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-ui.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-filesystem.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-media.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-appcompat.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/android-support-v4.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-locale.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-network.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/thirdparty.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-xml.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-platform.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-utils.jar" "/Users/dariorusignuolo/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-database.jar"
[ERROR] :  Failed to run dexer:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[ERROR] :  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/ko;
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:732)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
[ERROR] :  1 error; aborting
```

Comment: you can check [this thread](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/155815/already-added-lcomgoogleandroidgmsgamesachievementachievement)

Answer (score 0):

I simply delete the `ti.cloudpush` module from the `tiapp.xml` . it conflicts with `ti.cloud` module. they have one library in common that would included twice in the project

Answer (score 0):

just in case if anybody need `ti.cloudpush` AND `ti.cloud` libraries both in the project. I did a trick that worked in my case:

make a duplicate of the module without the conflicting library(ies) and select this new kind of clone module. hope this helps